# Disable onclick only in a page Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to disable an onclick action when i'm in a page.

I have a menu with 3 elements. I can click on each of them to reach a page. I have the button DICTIONARY. When I'm in page dictionary and i click on dictionary button, the onclick loads again the content! 
How can i solve this?

Thank you..

Comment: your question seems to be too broad

Comment: are you talking about a site you wrote or a 3rd party site to which you have no control over? if its the first case - show some code and be more specific about what you are trying to do and what have you done so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// To disable:

```
document.getElementById('id').style.pointerEvents = 'none';
```

// To re-enable:

```
document.getElementById('id').style.pointerEvents = 'auto';
```

// Use '' if you want to allow CSS rules to set the value

Answer (score 1):

You can try using

```
$('#urid').attr('onclick','').unbind('click');
```